# Review of network connectivity diagram

Tags: routing, vlan, ipv4, lan

Greeting's, this is my first attempt at network connectivity and hence would truly appreciate if community at large can review and guide me through it.

We have one main office with 7 branch offices. We don't plan to expand over 12-15 branch offices (even if we do, I feel my following assumptions and design should stand).

We plan to have P2P VPN lines between offices. I have proposed that we use 172.16/12 subnet. With 172.16.x.x for HQ and 172.17.x.x and so on for each branch. We will never have over 500 PC's per branch.

There are as of now 6 departments and I have proposed 172.16.1.x and so on for each department which will stay consistent over the branches.

We have (for whatever) reason L3 switches all around and each switch may hold computers of 2 or more departments. Hence to segregate I've proposed VLANs which will be (VLAN IDs) consistent between switches (I am unsure of this part). Hence, if sales computers are in VLAN2 on switch 2. Other switches (switch 3 for example) will have VLAN2 holding subnet and PC dedicated to sales. I've attached a diagram for better explanation.
I want to know if it's possible for inter VLAN communication based on the diagram I've attached and of course the changes recommend based on our needs.

I am certain of having made mistakes with trunking. Please do guide me through it. Will the firewall be able to see IP's of endpoint with trunking on uplinks and L3 switch. Also all the switches in the diagram are L3

[image]

Thanking you all in anticipation!

Edit:

My requirements are for L3VPN as per one of the answers. Thank you again. Just to confirm and reiterate since this is critical and my job hangs on getting it right - 
As someone suggested - I am planning to shift to 10/8 subnet for better expendability.
Hence:
1.  HQ will have 10.1.0.0 subnet

2. Branches will start with 10.2.0.0 series.
3. There will be further subdivision of IP ranges using VLANs per department. This will be consistent throughout the organization
   A.  Sales will be allocated 10.1.1.0 in HQ.
   B.  10.2.1.0 in branch 1 and 10.3.1.0 in branch 3 – so on and so forth.
   Network device topology will remain consistency throughout branches:
4. ISP CPE - Firewall - L3 Core swtich - L3 (working in L2 mode) switches - Endpoints.
   Physical topology between branches will be -
5. Endpoints - L2 Switches - L3 Core switch - firewall - ISP CPE - L3VPN - ISP CPE - Firewall - L3 Core swtich - L3 (working in L2 mode) switches - Endpoints.
   Topology with IP addresses for illustration will be: 
   Endpoints (10.1.1.5) - L2 Switches (10.1.5.2) - L3 Core switch (10.1.1.1) - firewall (10.1.1.250 - question - should this be on same subnet or is it better to have firewall IP as 10.1.0.250) - ISP CPE - L3VPN - ISP CPE - Firewall (10.2.1.250) - L3 Core swtich (10.2.1.1)- L3 (working in L2 mode) switches (10.1.5.2) - Endpoints (10.2.1.5)

Questions: 
1.  Is this optimum with respect to security (VLAN segregation for each departments), manageability, bandwidth (broadcast domains and compromised endpoint quarantine)?
2.  Will a machine on different VLAN and IP subnet (10.1.2.5) communicate with machine at HQ (10.1.1.5) and with 10.2.2.5 (at branch)? I reckon that within the same office (HQ/Branch) machines won't communicate. However, they will between branches of same department (10.1.1.5 with 10.2.1.5).

Thank you very very much to everyone who has reviewed and assisted me with this.

Second diagram 
[image: machine to machine between branch and HQ with IPs]

Comment: Does the firewall support multiple virtual interfaces(VLAN interfaces) basically router on a stick?

Comment: It's a Cisco ASA 5525-X model. Here is a CIsco document stating base model gets 200 VLAN licenses. Is this what you're inquiring about? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/data-sheet-c78-729807.html?mdfid=284143129

Comment: I would recommend using 10/8 for your addressing scheme instead of 172.16/12.   This way you have many more subnets to work with and it is more scalable.  You can assign a 10.x/16 supernet for each site and further subnet it for your various vlans.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

So here are a few points I would suggest:

- Create virtual interface of each VLAN on the firewall itself, and use it as gateway for each host in the VLAN.
- Try to get redundancy on the core switch, If stacking available please choose that.
- Use different VLAN for servers and again put its virtual interface on firewall itself(use that interface IP as gateway for servers), In this way you will have a DMZ for servers.
- Have a switch placed in the servers area as well, Do not connect them directly to the core switch.

> We will never have over 500 PC's per branch.

- **never** is a very strong word(avoid it) companies grow, networks grow. You **never** know when you will need new hardware for growing user base.
- You will have to **trunk** the ports between switches({department and core} and {server switch and core}) and also between the L3 core and firewall.
- Ports connected to hosts/servers are to be put in access vlan mode unless needed otherwise.
- Yes inter-vlan traffic will go through firewall(you can apply policies what to allow and what not) in this topology.
- Yes firewall will be directly able to see MACs of end hosts in this topology.

**UPDATE**
You can also have L3 as the gateway of each VLAN rather than firewall, I am writing some cons and pros of having firewall as gateway(and vice versa):

**Cons**

- Each host arp will come to firewall, you will have to see arp-cache size on firewall.
- For inter-vlan routing you have to make policy on firewall(blessing in disguise).
- SLAAC might not be available for IPv6 in firewall.
- If firewall goes down, Inter-vlan traffic will also stop.

**Pros**

- Lesser configuration overhead.
- You can have DMZs configured(allow/disallow different traffic from internet/intranet).
- More control over inter-vlan traffic.
- Switching faster than routing, Packets will be switched to firewall.
- Firewall will see all the hosts.

**UPDATE 2(after question was updated):**

Your diagram shows something else(than what you have explained). Anyways.

**From Diagram**: Do not use the management IP of switches from same VLAN as that clients! Use a separate network.

> L2 Switches (10.1.5.2)

L2 switches at both ends have same management IP, don't do that. Assign different management IP range(I take this is a typo).

> firewall (10.1.1.250 - question - should this be on same subnet or is it better to have firewall IP as 10.1.0.250)

Do not use the same network, its of no use. Use a point to point network(a /30) between L3 and firewall, Since in any case gateway of your VLANs will be the L3 so why complicate things(if you are going to use this topology i.e.)

> 1. Is this optimum with respect to security (VLAN segregation for each departments), manageability, bandwidth (broadcast domains and compromised endpoint quarantine)?

Yes seems like so till now(will update if something comes in my mind).

> 2. Will a machine on different VLAN and IP subnet (10.1.2.5) communicate with machine at HQ (10.1.1.5) and with 10.2.2.5 (at branch)?

As you said you are using L3VPN(routes are advertised via bgp mostly from one end router to another), So for example 10.1.0.0/8 from HQ is advertised to all the other branches via L3VPN and 10.2.0.0/8 from a branch to HQ, they will be able to communicate. So in essence, depending on how much routes your ISP lets you advertise. You can achieve this easily if the HQ office has routes of branch office and vice versa.

> I reckon that within the same office (HQ/Branch) machines won't communicate. However, they will between branches of same department (10.1.1.5 with 10.2.1.5).

Is this something you think, or something you want. Because this won't happen by default. Its rather reverse of what you think(presuming) The local VLANs will be able to talk via inter-vlan(via L3) routing(since you have configured GWs of each VLAN on L3 itself). Also for different offices(HQ/branch) departments to talk you will need L3VPN routes transported(as explained above, job of ISP), though you can also achieve this with NAT(config overhead).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it would be simpler if the OP uses the L3 switch as the core instead of using the fw as the gateway for all VLANs.

Comment: Yes you may, But this topology was suggested for various reasons( easier manageability in inter-vlan routing, DMZs, Firewall will be able to see each end host) On top of all this there will be one less routing hop!

Comment: Thank you all of you. While I'm trying to assimilate the information provided. I had a question about using L3 core switch as gateway or firewall. Will the hosts be able to access internet if the gateway is L3 core switch. If so do i require a rule or a route for internet access?

Comment: Yes you will need a **default** route towards firewall and static **routes** of each of your LAN segments on your firewall towards your L3, Plus NAT each of your LAN segment with public IPs, as the private IPs are not routable!

Comment: @user31781 updated answer with some pros and cons of having firewall as gateway of VLANs/

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. I will assimilate this and get back with any questions I may have. Again, thank you both very very much.

Comment: A question, if I use the L3 switch as gateway will the firewall not see host IP? I am asking because I want to block traffic of hosts using firewall and I will need the firewall to see IP which is requesting access.

Comment: Yes for that purpose you will see them!

Comment: Thank you Anirudh and Ron. I have few more questions - When I extend this network over a VPN (or P2P VPN - [is it different?]) How do i get computers on same VLAN IDs (or department since they'll be divided using departments) to communicate only to same department machine over the VPN.

So a machine in DC having IP subnet 172.16.x.x when communicating with 172.17.x.x in toronto.. with same topography 

(machine - L2 switch - L3 switch - firewall - CPE - internet - CPE - firewall - L3 Switch - L2 switch - machine) 
How can i extend availability of servers from HQ to branches?

Comment: Well VPN is virtual private network(connection between **two** or more hosts), P2P vpn is a type of VPN. I don't know what you have communicated to your ISP regarding your requirements. P2P(peer to peer) is between two hosts, So if you want to route all your traffic to HQ and NAT it from there(for better control), use this VPN technique. Yes all the machines at branch offices and HQ will be able to talk in this case. Is that what you need? Otherwise ISP do L3VPNs also in which all your offices can talk over a private network, and can go to the internet independently!

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra I've updated the question. Kindly have a look.

Comment: @user31781 updated the answer, we can chat if you have doubts.

Comment: Thanks a million @AnirudhMalhotra . My Goal is to allow machines from same department communicate irrespective of their location and no communication between machines of different business streams (sales can't communicate with marketing irrespective of their location - within HQ or HQ to branch communication). How do is best achieve this? Since L3 Switch is what I feel will serve best as gateway.

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra I would however want one subnet (10.x.5.x) to be accessible from all parts of the network as this will hold servers. :)

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra I am unable to initialize chat due to my reputation on the website being low.

Comment: **no communication between machines of different business streams (sales can't communicate with marketing irrespective of their location - within HQ or HQ to branch communication).** -- Well in that case it would be better if you have gateway directly on firewall. Since that way you will be able to regulate what you want to allow(10.x.5.x) or deny. @RonTrunk would agree on this. Also about chat I couldn't start one because of your reps(tried explicit write access, that also didnt work). You can reach me on twitter though [at]anirudh_m1

Comment: Your requirements make this a complex design, and no, I don't think the firewall as gateway is a good idea.  I think it will become a bottleneck for your network.  I think you will have to put ACLs on your switches, or consider other mechanisms such as SGT.

Comment: And I don't mean to sound rude, but you're asking us to design a complex network for you -- that's something a lot of us get paid to do.  I'm happy to answer a question or two, but you might consider getting some (paid) professional advice, if you think you're in over your head and, as you say, your job is on the line.

Comment: @RonTrunk He already doesn't want the deptts to talk to each other! So i dont know how you say that it will be a bottleneck, Same could be said for the gateway on L3

Comment: @RonTrunk Thank you very much. What would be the best solution to complex business requirements without creating choke points?

Comment: @RonTrunk I appreciate your responses. I am sorry for what seems a spoon feeding, however this is a learning curve for me. Kindly accept my apologies and I will cease questioning here. Please discard my previous question. I did not see your message before asking my question. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra If you're comfortable helping me design my company network even with correct points highlighted by RonTrunk, please let me know. Also I truly appreciate all the hand holding :)

Comment: There isn't a simple answer to your question that will fit into this comment box.    There are probably more requirements to consider that you haven't told us about yet.  I don't know what part of the world you're in, but I would recommend seeking some professional advice.

Comment: @user31781 Sure message me on twitter!

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra I've sent a request and you need to follow me too for IM to work.

Comment: I am sorry i still don't have your ID Or I cannot see you following me?

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra I am following you my ID starts with / at \ pa.....

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  Here are a few observations:

- It's generally a good idea to push layer 3 as close to the end users
  as possible.  Since you have layer 3 switches everywhere, this is
  easy for you to do.
- You should consider creating a routing hierarchy, with the branch
  switch terminating the local VLANs, and the core switch terminating
  the branch links.
- While it's fine to put each department on a separate VLAN, unless you
  plan to restrict access between departments, there's no real value.
- It's more important to insure that there are no layer 2 links
  connecting your branch offices.  Everything should be L3.  I don't
  see a need to use trunking anywhere.
- Place your servers on their own VLAN for design consistency and also
  since that's the most likely place to enforce policy.

Comment: According to questioner there may be 500 users in a branch how do you plan to accommodate that without any L2 links?

Comment: I don't see the problem.  Create as many VLANs as needed at each branch..

Comment: But all the hosts cannot connect to a single switch(for obvious reasons), Therefore more switches needed! How to connect multiple switches? I don't think you would want to configure point to point IPs between them, Would you? That too won't make sense for connecting same VLANs on different switches.

Comment: As I said, unless the OP is trying to restrict inter department traffic, there's little value in VLAN per department.  It's better to have VLAN per area (floor/bldg/site).  More importantly, if you trunk VLANs all the way back to the FW, you create a failure domain across the entire network.  A problem at one branch can take down everything.

Comment: Also, we don't know what the branch switches are.  It could be a chassis or stackable switches.   Not that that changes things.

Comment: **"A problem at one branch can take down everything"** -- I do not see how, and how having an L3 would avoid it! As far as I know broadcast domains are separated by VLANs. On your second point of not having a VLAN per department, Having it per site -- You still didn't explain how 500 users will connect to switch(es) without having an L2(trunk or default vlan) port between them. Also what about the broadcast domain being of 500 users. Every broadcast goes to 500 users! eventually choking the network if some malicious machine present!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47922/discussion-between-ron-trunk-and-anirudh-malhotra).

Comment: Just to help everyone give me more accurate answer - The switches are HP - 5130 (will function as L2) and HP - 5900 (L3 / Core switch). Firewall is Cisco ASA 5525-x with possibility of 200 VLANs (as per current license)

Further the purpose of VLAN segregation is for security.

Comment: @RonTrunk Thank you very much for your observations. Kindly help me with the updated diagram. Thank you once again.